# Has my @ notification to a user worked?

Tags: support, comment-replies

I asked [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15265809/1577396), and a user named `Molecular Man` answered it correctly. I don't know why, but he just deleted his post. I just [@ notified him in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265809/select-a-one-of-the-containers-from-panel-in-extjs#comment21535051_15265809) to ask him why he deleted his post. but I have not had a reply.

I just want to know whether the user has been notified of my comment or not? (I am just curious about it, because there is no response from that user)

Comment: No, he does not get the ping.

Comment: The `@` works only in comments where the pinged user has posted comment as well, or had activity in the post itself (e.g. edit, vote to close etc). You'll have to post comment on one of his old posts asking him why he deleted his answer, then remember to delete your comment shortly if he doesn't respond.

Comment: Is this anyway to call that user. I would like to say that his post was correct. So that I can award him the points.

Comment: @Mr_Green unless he left contact info in his profile (he has link to blog, but can't see any way for direct contact) then yes, that's your only option. It's not a good one, but it works and if you delete your comment soon after posting it it won't create too much noise.

Comment: well  why bother .. move on and wait .. you will probably find a better working answer by someone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, he didn't get notification of your reply, because you replied him on your question, where he has neither commented nor edited.

For more information on how comment replies work see this Meta Question:

- [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)